# how do i wrap the input with a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this format

```
<td class="value">
<input type="text" size="30" name="application[name]" id="application_name" data-validate="true" class="name">
</td>
```

and with jquery i need the final result to be this

```
<td class="value">
<div class="field_with_errors">
    <input type="text" size="30" name="application[name]" id="application_name" data-validate="true" class="name">
  <label style="color: rgb(204, 0, 0);" class="message" for="application_name">Required</label>
</div>
</td>
```

As you can see i have a wrapping div....i dont think i can achieve this with prepend. Here is my jquery so far and as you can see i have the input

```
 var form = $(".applications_form");
 var company_name = form.find(".name");
```

Comment: Check http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at jQuery.wrap()

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$("#application_name").wrap("<div class=\"field_with_errors\"></div>");
$("#application_name .field_with_errors").append("<label style=\"color: rgb(204, 0, 0);\" class=\"message\" for=\"application_name\">Required</label>");
```

The first line wraps the input with the div and the 2nd line appends the label.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) function, like this:

```
$('td.value').children().wrapAll('<div/>');
```

Edit: My mistake, I thought the `<label>` was in the existing HTML, when it seems to be added (though there's no mention of that!). If the `<input>` is indeed the only existing element, you can indeed use `.wrap()`, then use `.append()` to add the `<label>` element afterwards.

Possibly something like this:

```
var company_name = $('#application_name'); // you have a unique ID, may as well make use of it!
company_name.wrap('<div/>').parent().append('<label ...>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var $form = $(".applications_form");
 var $company_name = $form.find(".name"); 
 $company_name.wrap('<div class="field_with_errors" />');
```